# Beautifulsoup not finding certain tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to collect some data from an rss feed I have its link whose htmls goes somewhat like this.

```
 <channel>
    <title>Events</title>
    <description>Events</description>
    <link>https://www.hackerrank.com</link>
    <item>
      <title>Codechef - December Lunchtime 2017</title>
      <description></description>
      <url>https://www.codechef.com/LTIME55</url>
      <startTime>2017-12-30 14:00:00 UTC</startTime>
      <endTime>2017-12-30 17:00:00 UTC</endTime>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>Codechef - December Cook-Off 2017</title>
      <description></description>
      <url>https://www.codechef.com/COOK89</url>
      <startTime>2017-12-24 16:00:00 UTC</startTime>
      <endTime>2017-12-24 18:30:00 UTC</endTime>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

I am trying to find elements by tags title, start time and end time. But the only elements i get are the title elements.
The python code is as followed:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text,'html.parser')
endtime = soup.find_all("endTime")
print(endtime)
titles = soup.find_all("title")
print(titles)
```

The output is:

```
[]
[<title>....(The required data)....]
```

Comment: This is XML not HTML. This is not a reason for your output, just a correction.

Comment: so should i use beautifullstonesoup?

Comment: @Vidhyanshujain check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, once `BeautifulSoup` parse your plain text, it converts all tags to `lower case`, for example pass `endtime`

```
soup.find_all('endtime')
[<endtime>2017-12-30 17:00:00 UTC</endtime>,
 <endtime>2017-12-24 18:30:00 UTC</endtime>]
```

Comment: you need to pass `values` the way I passed in above example, use my code